# Select element into foreach Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm on Symfony2 with Twig and i have 2 array in param :

My controller :

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
                             array('checked' => $boxChecked,
                                   'choices' => $choices));
```

Vars 'checked' and 'choices' are two arrays, I want to show the value of $checked[$choices[$i]] to compare with true ofr false to apply checked or not into input into twig tpl.

This is my code but does'nt work :

```
{% for choice in choices %}

      {% if checked.{{choice}} == true %}

        <div class="choice">{{ choice|capitalize }} <input type="checkbox" id="{{ choice }}" /></div>

    {% else %}

        <div class="choice">{{ choice|capitalize }} <input type="checkbox" id="{{ choice }}" checked="checked" /> </div>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

error is : `Expected name or number in &quot;MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig&quot; at line 22 (500 Internal Server Error)`

Line 22 is : `{% if checked.{{choice}} == true %}`

I don't know how have my checked.(MY VAR CHOICE into my foreach CHOICES) into twig tpl ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use brackets syntax instead:

```
    {% for choice in choices %}

          {% if checked[choice] == true %}

            <div class="choice">{{ choice|capitalize }} <input type="checkbox" id="{{ choice }}" /></div>

        {% else %}

            <div class="choice">{{ choice|capitalize }} <input type="checkbox" id="{{ choice }}" checked="checked" /> </div>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```